# If we form an investment company, then are the expenses deductible?

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, tax-deduction

It is commonly known that if we are individual investors in the USA, then if we need to investigate smartphones and see how they work with the 7nm, 5nm chipset, or attend shareholder meetings, it is all non tax-deductible.

But what if we form an investment company instead?  For example, when Warren Buffett formed the investment company and needed to visit the Railroad company to join their shareholder meeting or visit or talk to the VPs, it would appear it naturally is tax-deductible.

Comment: I wish there was a requirement for giving a reason why people downvote things. What is the point of downvoting this question? Why? What good does that serve?

Comment: I think I have seen that in the movie, and the answer is, "because they 'feel like it'"

Answer (score 1):

An investment company is usually in two parts, the management company and the fund. The management company incurs expenses such as employee compensation, rent, and travel. These expenses are tax-deductible to the management company as normal business expense.

The fund incurs expenses including management fees. These are deducted from the returns of the fund, and are also not taxed.

Unfortunately for amateur investors and investing clubs, a federal tax law in 2017 [restricted](https://www.schwab.com/resource-center/insights/content/investment-expenses-whats-tax-deductible) the deductibility of investment expenses. But even prior to that law, [deductibility was limited](https://www.stockcentral.com/forum/posts/t4494-Club-Expenses---Deductible-or-not) to the rare occasion of having expenses exceeding 2% of your AGI.

Comment: so the rich is not taxed, but the middle classes are. But then, who can say I am amateur? I form a formal company and I am an amateur and it has to be who to be "professional"?

Comment: @StefanieGauss, it’s because it’s not a business.  You would be a professional investor if people were paying you to invest their money.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a company, then any expense which is for operating the company is tax-deductible. But only if it is actually for business purposes. When you buy something through the company but end up using it for private purpose, then it isn't.

For example, it is also a business expense when you buy a smartphone and use it primarily for business communication. But when you buy a smartphone for personal use, then it isn't a business expense.

The same applies to travel expenses. When you travel in order to meet with business partners, attend trade conferences or do research, then that's a business expense. When you are taking a vacation and go sightseeing, it is not.

There are of course a lot of cases which are in grey areas. Like a smartphone you use both for business and for private use. Or a trip you take both for business and for pleasure. There is a lot of case law regarding what is and isn't tax-deductible. If you have any questions if a specific thing is tax deductible in your particular circumstances, then ask your tax consultant.

Comment: I buy the smartphone to use for a week and then to disassemble and look at its parts. That's "business" enough, isn't it?

Comment: @StefanieGauss If that's part of your business activity, then it likely would be. But I am not a tax consultant, so I can not guarantee you that. Ask your tax consultant for details.

Comment: If you found clients to pay you to reverse engineer cellphones then sure, buying and reverse engineering a cellphone would be a business expense which could be deducted off your revenue.  If your “business” is passively investing your own money in a public company by buying an extremely small percentage of common stock in a phone company; that’s not a business that’s just you investing your money.  This has nothing to do with the rich.